# PyTorch indexing by argmax

Tags: indexing, pytorch, vectorization, tensor

Dear community I have a challenge with regard to tensor indexing in PyTorch. The problem is very simple. Given a tensor create an index tensor to index its maximum values per column.

```py
x = T.tensor([[0, 3, 0, 5, 9, 8, 2, 0], 
              [0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 9, 1, 0]])
```

Given this tensor I would like to build a boolean mask for indexing its maximum values per colum. To be specific I do not need its maximum values, `torch.max(x, dim=0)`, nor its indices, `torch.argmax(x, dim=0)`, but a boolean mask for indexing other tensor based on this tensor max values. My ideal output would be:

```py
# Input tensor
x
tensor([[0, 3, 0, 5, 9, 8, 2, 0],
        [0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 9, 1, 0]])

# Ideal output bool mask tensor
idx
tensor([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

I know that `values_max = x[idx]` and `values_max = x.max(dim=0)` are equivalent but I am not looking for `values_max` but for `idx`.

I have built a solution around it but it just seem to complex and I am sure `torch` have an optimized way to do this. I have tried to use `torch.index_select` with the output of `x.argmax(dim=0)` but failed so I built a custom solution that seems to cumbersome to me so I am asking for help to do this in a vectorized / tensorial / torch way.

Comment: Should it only highlight the first entry? Otherwise mask = t == t.max(dim=0).values looks kinda close enough.

Comment: Yes only the first entry since I need to mask another tensor with `len(new_tensor) = x.shape[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform this operation by first extracting the index of the maximum value column-wise of your tensor with [`torch.argmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.argmax.html), setting `keepdim` to `True`

```
>>> x.argmax(0, keepdim=True)
tensor([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Then you can use [`torch.scatter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.scatter.html) to place `1`s in a zero tensor at the designated indices:

```
>>> torch.zeros_like(x).scatter(0, x.argmax(0,True), value=1)
tensor([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: thank you Ivan the scatter function is the one I was looking for :) I tried `torch.index_select` and `torch.gather` but `torch.scatter` is exactly the opposite but did not know it